# 2 Columns for labels and their items

Tags: html, css, layout, seo

What's the best markup approach for SEOs to render 2 column layouts: 1 column for labels and the 2nd column for their items.

I wrote two examples:  I would think DT/DD would be best suited since they already couple a title with a definition and they don't need to use label tags to couple/associate items together; but I also used ULs and labels as a second example.

**JS Fiddle link:** http://jsfiddle.net/ryanjohnsond/cyk13g3x/

```
ol, ul,label, dt, dd {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
label, dt{
    color: #B4886B;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
}
label:after, dt:after { content: ": " }
```

```
<dl>
    <dt>Silly</dt>
    <dd>Puppies</dd>
    <dt>Silly</dt>
    <dd>Puppies</dd>
    <dt>Silly</dt>
    <dd>Puppies</dd>
</dl>
```

```
<ul id="label-test">
    <li><label for="campers" class="labels">Happy</label>
        <span id="campers">Campers</span></li>
    <li><label for="puppies" class="labels">Silly</label>
        <span id="puppies">Puppies</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The DT/DD method is more semantic and generally seems like the best way to display the information as you have it presented. In special cases where microformats or microdata could be used on the parent element to provide additional SEO benefit, the UL/LI method would provide the structure you need.